# Create View to show all documents in folder only

Tags: document-library, list-view

I am using SharePoint 2010.

I have a document library and lots of folders in the library.

I want to create a view with all the document inside 1 of those folders.

Can this be done without having to add a custom column into my library?
The problem that I have is, if I tag the document with a value of say "Category" and I add a document to that view it want to place the document inside the root of the library in stead of the folder where all those documents are kept.

You have to manually go and select the folder each time when you upload a document.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a feature called the Content Organizer to do this. Content Organizer rules can be created to route items to a folder automatically depending on the value of the metadata. You can set these rules up individually or have a single rule that creates folders based on the value of a field. Users would still need to tag the document, but then the routing to the appropriate folder would be automatic.

It depends on the way your folders are organised whether this is a practical solution for you, but I think it is worth investigating.